# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a Angular 8 application but I get an error on the click event
I have this html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="saveAndPublish()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save & Publish</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-node-tree-input formControlName="nodes"></app-node-tree-input>
</form>
```

and this is the js code:

```
 constructor(
    private i18n: I18n,
    private schemaTemplateService: SchemaTemplateService,
    private blockerService: ScreenBlockerService,
    route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.schema = route.snapshot.data["schema"];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nodes: this.fb.control(this.schema.nodes)
    });
  }
```

But I get this error:

> EditSchemaComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'click' of undefined

This are the other methods:

```
 save() {
    const model = this.getSubmitModel();

    if (model) {
      this.blockerService
        .blockWhileWorking(this.schemaTemplateService.createVersion(model.name, model), this.i18n("Saving..."))
        .subscribe(schema => {
          // TODO feedback
        });
    }
  }

  saveAndPublish() {
    const model = this.getSubmitModel();

    this.blockerService
      .blockWhileWorking(
        this.schemaTemplateService.createVersion(model.name, model).pipe(
          flatMap(template => {
            return this.schemaTemplateService.publish(this.schema.name, template.id);
          })
        ),
        this.i18n("Saving & Publishing...")
      )
      .subscribe(schema => {
        // TODO feedback
      });
  }
```

```
private getSubmitModel(): CreateSchemaDTO {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const value = this.form.value;
      return {
        name: this.schema.name,
        nodes: value.nodes
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show `saveAndPublish()` and `save()` methods?

Comment: And those are the only places where you have `click` in your template? Because this looks perfectly fine. No other errors in console? Imports OK?

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: Also, maybe in lines 1-2 there's something, dunno, a missing `>`, a duplicated "", something like that.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton is it possible to create a stackblitz example?

Comment: Are you refering to your html in your component?

Comment: probably the function getSubmitModel() is async, so the instruction below reads model as undefined, could u show that method (getSubmitModel)?

Comment: I edit the post